Output control with protection using MOSFETs for bench power supply
Recently I been making bench power supply powered with both barrel jack and USB-C with support up to 3A output.
I wanted to control output with ESP32 based MCU (3v3), it should be normally closed until we prepare the voltage and connect it to load with ability to switch it off during operation.
I also wanted to make sure that if higher voltage is applied to input it won't conduct potentially damaging rest of the circuit or power supply.
I wanted to create most efficient possible, of course it depends on components too but I bet I can find some good/cheap components on LCSC.
Here is schematic: https://tinyurl.com/2b59g39f

Is it possible to simplify it? I tried to use 2x PNP to check which voltage is higher. Is there anything that could bite me and what should I be aware of when selecting other components?
I followed it from design that will choose higher supply depending on what is connected: https://tinyurl.com/29ccr5w3

For interested I will put up finished design on my github once I test everything.

It's pretty neat that you're doing this on Falstad but I wouldn't recommend it if you're trying to simulate real and non-ideal behavior. Falstad is meant to be an educational tool that simulates a perfect world. So as of right now, it's difficult to answer your question because you're not using real components.

I selected MOSFET with "beta" from data from something I want to use. Of course is not perfect and I would need to add capacitors and proper resistors to mimic it but I am just asking for general idea of logic would work like that.
What you recommend for analysis like that?
